# can't find ERROR in an revers array of characters problem?

Tags: c

Hello guys im trying to reverse array of characters but i can find the issue ;
this is my code :

this is function to calc a length of array

```
int str_len(int *str) 
{
    int index;

    while (str[index] != '\0')
    {
        index++;
    }

    return (index);
}
```

this is the code to reverse characters

```
void ft_rev_int_tab(int *tab, int size)
{
    size = str_len(tab);
  
    while(size >= 0)
    {
        tab[size];
        size--;
    } 
}
```

i'm not trying nothing yet

Comment: What do you think this statement does:  `tab[size];`  Hint:  It does nothing other than load an a value and then discard the result.  A good optimizing compiler would optimize it away.  It doesn't look like you've made a serious effort to write that function.  Also, your code is very hard to read due to the sloppy indentation.  A good starting point would be to clean it up.

Comment: What is the initial value of the variable `index` in your `str_len` function? If you think it's zero you need to study more of the very basics of C.

Comment: What's worse, `tab` is not a string. Only strings are null-terminated. A null-terminated string would be an array of *characters*, not of integers.

Comment: ooh yes of curse , bad mistake , it run fine now thank you, i have also missed initialisation Index with 0 ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ft_rev_int_tab` function is not actually manipulating anything. First, you state that you're trying to reverse characters but you're passing in an `int`, not characters. Then, after passing it in, you need to actually manipulate data. We can do that here by creating two starting points and working our way from the outsides in. We swap the two ends, move one step towards the inside, then swap those two, then rinse and repeat while your start position is less than your end position.

Here is some example code:

```c
int str_len(char *str) {
    int index = 0;
    
    while (str[index] != '\0') {
        index++;
    }
    
    return index;
}

void ft_rev_int_tab(char *tab, int size) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = size - 1;

    while (start < end) {
        // Swap the characters at the start and end positions
        char temp = tab[start];
        tab[start] = tab[end];
        tab[end] = temp;

        // Move the start and end positions towards each other
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "Hello, World!";
    int length = str_len(str);
    ft_rev_int_tab(str, length);
    printf("Reversed string: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you sure, the code you provide is working and clean but i have to pass an int *tab as a paramtre and not an char , anyway i find the solution thank you very much